# Socket.io --- One object for multiple users

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am building an application in node.js with socket.io where I want people to be able to vote on questions and have a timer included which will give them a time limit for answering questions.  The issue that I am running into (which I will highlight below) is that every time someone connects to the page, it will log the tick from the stopwatch object another time.  Even after people leave, it will continue to log it one time for every time someone connected.  Here is my code for the project thus far.

Stopwatch.js:

```
function Stopwatch() {
    if (false === (this instanceof Stopwatch)) {
        return new Stopwatch();
    }

    this.hour = 3600000;
    this.minute = 60000;
    this.second = 1000;
    this.time = this.hour;
    this.interval = undefined;

    events.EventEmitter.call(this);

    _.bindAll(this, 'start', 'stop', 'reset', 'onTick');
    };

    util.inherits(Stopwatch, events.EventEmitter);

    Stopwatch.prototype.start = function() {
        console.log("Starting the Timer!");
        this.interval = setInterval(this.onTick, this.second);
        this.emit('start');
    };

    Stopwatch.prototype.onTick = function() {
        var remainder = this.time,
        numhours,
        numMinutes,
        numSeconds,
        output = "";

        if (this.time === 0) {
            this.stop();
            return;
        }

        numHours = String(parseInt(remainder / this.hour, 10));
        remainder -= this.hour * numHours;

        numMinutes = String(parseInt(remainder / this.minute, 10));
        remainder -= this.minute * numMinutes;

        numSeconds = String(parseInt(remainder / this.second, 10));

        output = _.map([numHours, numMinutes, numSeconds], function(str) {
            if (str.length === 1) {
                 str = "0" + str;
            }
            return str;
        }).join(":");

        this.emit('tick', output);
        this.time -= this.second;
    }

    module.exports = Stopwatch;
}
```

socket.js:

```
var Stopwatch = require('../models/stopwatch');
var people = {};
var stopwatch = Stopwatch();

module.exports = function (io) {

    io.on('connection', function (socket) {
        //console.log("Someone joined...");

        //socket.on('join', function () {
        if (Object.keys(people).length === 0) {
            console.log('host joined');
            people[socket.id] = {"name": "host", "image": "fake picture", "host": true};
        } else {
            console.log("Someone else joined");
            people[socket.id] = {"name": "person", "image": "other picture", "host": false};
        }
        console.log(people);
    //});

    socket.on('startTimer', function() {
        stopwatch.start();
    });
    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        delete people[socket.id];
        console.log("someone left");
        console.log(people);
    });
    stopwatch.on('tick', function(time) {
            console.log(socket.id + '---stopwatch tick!' + time);
            socket.emit('timer', { countdown: time });
        });
    });
};
```

The javascript on the client:

```
var socket;

$(document).ready(function() {
    socket = io();

    socket.on('timer', function (data) {
        $('#timer').html(data.countdown);
    });

    $('#start-timer').click(function() {
        socket.emit('startTimer');
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance!  I can't figure out why it still logs each user and the time, even after they disconnect from the server.

Comment: I can't seem to find handling part of client disconnection.

Comment: Sorry, I just added it, I only copied over the parts of my code that are important so it wouldn't be as long and accidentally removed that part.

Comment: I believe the issue is coming from multiple event listeners on the single stopwatch, and I might need to remove event listeners when certain people leave the room.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's happening is that every time a new client opens a connection to the server, you're assigning an event listener to the `stopwatch` and never remove it, this causes the behaviour you're experiencing. You must remove your eventListener when the socket disconnects as stated in the [node event emitter class](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_removelistener_event_listener).

You should end up with something like this:

```js
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  //console.log("Someone joined...");

  //socket.on('join', function () {
  if (Object.keys(people).length === 0) {
    console.log('host joined');
    people[socket.id] = {"name": "host", "image": "fake picture", "host": true};
  } else {
    console.log("Someone else joined");
    people[socket.id] = {"name": "person", "image": "other picture", "host": false};
  }
  console.log(people);

  socket.on('startTimer', function() {
    stopwatch.start();
  });

  var _tickListener = function(time) {
    console.log(socket.id + '---stopwatch tick!' + time);
    socket.emit('timer', { countdown: time });
  };
  socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    delete people[socket.id];
    stopwatch.removeListener('tick', _tickListener);
    console.log("someone left");
    console.log(people);
  });
  stopwatch.on('tick', _tickListener);
});
```

Comment: Awesome, this will work well for when people disconnect!  Do you know of a way to simply prevent the event listeners from being add, or to keep one main event listener for the stopwatch?  I have found functions from the Emitter class that can set a limit on them, but they don't restrict more from being added, they just give me a warning whenever more than the limit are added.  I am trying to also understand what is happening here on my backend code.  Why is a new event listener added each time?  There is one "copy" or instance of base.js on my server, so why does it need to keep creating them?

Comment: @ThomasScully you're always  adding listeners because the `connection` event from the socket.io instance is fired every time a new user connects. As such all the code under the `io.on('connection', function (socket) { ...})` callback will be executed when a client connects. One way of maintaining a single `tick` listener for the `stopwatch` instance would be to set it outside the io on connection callback and, when the event fires, emit the 'timer' to all the connected sockets like `stopwatch.on('tick', function (time) { io.emit('timer', { countdown: time }) });`

Comment: Oh wow. I can't believe I didn't see that earlier.  Thank you for all the help!